# Finding the minimum $n$ such that there are $n$ reals $x_i$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n\sin x_i=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^ni\sin x_i=2019$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

How to solve this problem?

> $\sin x_i$ satisfies that, $\left(1\leqslant i\leqslant n\right)$
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sin x_i=0,\qquad \text{where }x_i\in\mathbb{R} 
> \end{equation}
> Moreover, $\sin x_i$ also satisfies that
> \begin{equation}
> \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cdot\sin x_i=2019
> \end{equation}
> Here is the question. How to find the minimum of $n$, where $n$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Think of the sinuses as numbers between -1 and 1, and prove that the best you can do is have them all equal to 1 or -1 (except at most one of them that must be 0) and all -1 has to be associated with small indices $i$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following expression, which (assuming $n$ is even) represents $\sum i \cdot \sin(x_i)$ where the first $\frac{n}{2}$ entries satisfy $\sin(x_i) = -1$ and the rest satisfy $\sin(x_i) = 1$, which clearly maximizes your second sum.

The expression, which amounts to adding the first $n$ numbers, then subtracting the first $\frac{n}{2}$ numbers *twice* (since we don't just want to take them away, we actually want to change the sign on them) is:

$$f(n) = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} - 2 \cdot \frac{(\frac{n}{2})(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{2}$$

Suppose $f(n) = 2019$, which would be right-on-the-nose-optimal.  Then you get:

$$\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} - 2 \cdot \frac{(\frac{n}{2})(\frac{n}{2}+1)}{2} = 2019 \implies \text{multiply by 4}$$

$$2(n)(n+1) - (n)(n+2) = 8076 \implies n^2 = 8076 \implies n = 89.86\text{ish}$$

Since this formula applies to even $n$, it means that $n$ must be greater than $88$.  So it's sufficient to find a solution with $n = 89$.  Note that $(89)(90)/2 - (44)(45) = 2025$ which represents selecting the first $44$ entries so that $\sin(x_i) = -1$ and the rest to $1$.  Zeroing out the middle entry gives us an insufficient sum again, and this is maximal among such sums with $89$ entries.

Thus we are looking for a solution with $n = 90$.  For such a solution, consider $(1/2)(90)(91) - (45)(46) = 2025$, which is setting the first 45 entries to negative and the last $45$ entries to positive.  To decrease this sum by $6$ and achieve our desired $2019$, just swap the signs on $x_{44}$ and $x_{47}$, giving us a solution with $n = 90$, as desired.

Comment: You can probably cut out the even/odd step in the middle with a more well-conceived formula, but I screwed this proof up the first time and I just want to be done with it haha  I HATE competition-style math, I'm a total dunce at such things.  I think the comment below your post was basically to establish this ahead of time in a cleaner way.